# need oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, top-n

I am practising Oracle Subqueries.. (I am new to Oracle.)

**Question: Find the Highest Earning Employee in each Department?**

My query below works (BUT I feel its not that good, even though I get the correct result )

```
select e.deptid, e.name, e.salary 
from employee e 
where e.salary = (select max(salary) 
                  from employee b 
                  where b.deptid = e.deptid )
```

Is there another easy way? (Using inner joins or some other way?)

And I also am wondering: When exactly do we have to use Inner joins instead of using SubQueries?  When exactly do we have to use SubQueries instead of Inner joins?

Comment: your query _doesn't work_ for cases when lots of employees have same salaries

Comment: why it doesn't work when having more employees?, BTW Employee and Department are  different tables... 

Do u know any other way to write query for above prob?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the proposed duplicate...it is doing something quite different.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - okay, how about this one? http://stackoverflow.com/q/1533240/146325

Comment: That works better for me...

Answer (score 1):

Why using JOIN here?

```
select 
  deptid,
  min(name) keep (dense_rank first order by salary desc),
  max(salary)
from 
  employee 
group by
  deptid
```

Comment: i didnt get this:  min(name) keep (dense_rank first order by salary desc),  


BTW, Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

**I have got another query as below:**

```
select dept_id, fname,salary 
from (select dept_id, fname,salary, 
      rank() over (order by salary desc) ranking 
      from department d, employee e 
      where d.dept_id = e.deptid) where ranking=1;
```

I feel above is correct, **BUT i have  a doubt in my above query:** I didnt used any Joins in my query BUT still iam able to retrive columns from 2 tables.. (so no use of joins?)

Comment: You don't use any data from DEPARTMENT so why do you think you need to include it in the query?  But anyway, your inner query does have a join, it just uses the oder syntax of the WHERE clause rather than the ANSI `join ... on ` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

you were close - you'r missing the order by salary in `rank`

```
select *
from ( 
    select  dept_id , fname , salary , 
            rank() over (partition by dept_id order by salary) as rnk 
    from    department d, employee e 
    where   d.dept_id = e.deptid
where rnk = 1
```